# Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DateTimeSerializer' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer`

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

While searching for the solution I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421379/mongodb-custom-collection-serializer) and [this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/) but the concept was not clear to me so couldn't implement it :(. 
This error occurs when I try to update values in the database(specifically for datetime objects). Below is the code that I'm using:-

```
     var update = Builders<Model>.Update
            .Set(t => t.startdate, BsonValue(objModel.startdate));
     var result = model.UpdateOne(query, update);
```

and BonValue function is as follows:-

```
   private static BsonValue BsonValue(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return (BsonValue)obj ?? BsonNull.Value;
        else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(string))
            return new BsonString(obj.ToString());
        else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
            return new BsonDateTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(obj.ToString()), DateTimeKind.Utc));
        else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(int))
            return new BsonInt32(int.Parse(obj.ToString()));
        else
            return (BsonValue)obj;
    }
```

I think this is because I have started using upgraded packages of mongoDB.Bson  and mongoDB.Driver. Current version is 2.3.0

any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

1) while Inserting data what i do is as follows:-

```
    BsonDocument objBsonDoc = new BsonDocument {
            { "startdate",DataManager.GetBsonValue( objModel.startdate) }
        }; return dbHelper.CreateDocument(Model.CollectionName, objBsonDoc);
```

In objBsonDoc I can see the StartDate value but after CreateDocument command StartDate doesn't get saved in DB.

2) This is what I'm doing while updating values:-

```
    public static long Edit(Model objModel, string id)
    {
        IMongoCollection<Model> model = dbHelper.GetCollection<Model>(Model.CollectionName);

        var query = Builders<Model>.Filter.Eq(t => t.id, ObjectId.Parse(id));

        var update = Builders<Model>.Update
            .Set(t => t.startdate, objModel.startdate);

        var result = model.UpdateOne(query, update);
        return result.MatchedCount;
    }
```

here also i get the value for start date and also getting modifiedcount=1 but still when i check DB it shows null for start sate.

My Model class:-

```
    public class Model
{
    public static string CollectionName
    {
        get { return "Collection"; }
    }

    public ObjectId id { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime startdate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need to perform your own conversion the way you are.

Try setting the BsonRepresentation on your model

```
public class Model
{
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
}
```

For the sake of clarify can i suggest you rename your collection variable to collection instead of model as this in confusing, so

```
IMongoCollection<Model> collection = dbHelper.GetCollection<Model>(Model.CollectionName);

Model objModel = new Model { startDate = DateTime.UtcNow };
collection.InsertOne(yourModel);
```

And to perform your update you won't need to set to BsonValue

```
 var query = Builders<Model>.Filter.Eq(t => t.Id, ObjectId.Parse(id));
 var update = Builders<Model>.Update.Set(t => t.startdate, objModel.startdate);
 var result = model.UpdateOne(query, update);
```

One suggestion, is to store your ObjectId as string and use BsonRepresentation as you have with DateTime:

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
[BsonId]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

That way you don't need to go out of your way to parse it to ObjectId and it works the same, so your filter becomes

```
var query = Builders<Model>.Filter.Eq(t => t.Id, id);
```

Or you could use Lambda directly in your update like so:

```
var update = Builders<Model>.Update
    .Set(t => t.Id == id, objModel.startdate);
```

Comment: I have tried as u said but I'm getting modified count as zero always.

Comment: Modified count will only return if the record was actually modified. If there were no changes to the document it will be zero. What are you filtering, what is in your "query" variable? Chances are you are either not matching any records

Comment: even if i get modified count as 1 the record doesn't store date values in DB.

Comment: I have this exact code working locally without issue. Can you please update your question to include your "query" variable. If the modified count is 1 then the document has certainly been modified. If you are saying the date field is not being updated then please check the value of objModel.startdate before you execute the update to ensure that this value is different from the one already saved in the db

Comment: Can you please also share you "Model" class please. I do not understand why you are doing what you are doing to populate objBsonDoc . I think you are over complicating it

Comment: Added model class pieperu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126574/discussion-between-newbiecoder-and-pieperu).

Comment: Thank u so much Pieperu everything is working fine now. Appreciate your help. Thanks a lot buddy.